# Canvas: trying to draw too large(120422400bytes) bitmap

Tags: android, firebase, android-imageview, android-canvas

Hello im trying to upload an image from my app to firebase but when image is selected from gallery but not showing in the image view and after that app crash with this

> Error  Canvas: trying to draw too large(120422400bytes) bitmap.

it happens with only few images which has a very high resolution

i have tried hardware acceleration to false but didnt worked for me

also any solution for how to minimize the resolution of images uploaded to database maximum should be 4k

> If you want see the code for the adapter class please tell me i will
> update my question

**Here is my code**

**Upload_Fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/upload_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/done_button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/upload_image_button"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upload_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
        android:text="@string/gallery"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Upload_Fragment.java**

```
public class Upload_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 10;
    Button chooseImageButton;
    TextView doneImageButtonButton;
    private ImageView uploadImageView;
    private Uri mImageUri;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private StorageTask mUploadTask;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, container, false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        chooseImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_button);
        doneImageButtonButton = view.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        uploadImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_view);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        doneImageButtonButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        chooseImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> openFileChooser());
        doneImageButtonButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload in Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                uploadToFirebase(mImageUri);
            }


        });

        return view;
    }


    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            doneImageButtonButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(uploadImageView);

        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = requireActivity().getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadToFirebase(Uri mImageUri) {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            reference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        reference.getDownloadUrl()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                                    Upload upload = new Upload(uri.toString());
                                    String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                                    databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                                });
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(snapshot -> {
                        double progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Ocurred" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: you're drawing a picture that is larger than the canvas can handle. What is your question for us?

Comment: what could be a solution for it

Comment: i mean what to do if a user select this kind of imags  ,how can i limit the size or any solution ,sorry i dont have the exact word to mention problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

This means your image too large to be draw on canvas.

**Solution:**
compress your image using any online tool like [Tiny PNG](https://tinypng.com/)